# Instance variable and thread safety in java

Tags: java, thread-safety, instance

Below is an example class (modified from the one I was testing), I would like to know if this is a thread safe class.

I see other posts and blogs where its been answered that instance variables are not necessarily thread safe. (most of the examples shown with primitive types)

When I create the OutputResponse object outside the method and load test it from soapui it was failing, but when I create the object inside the method the load test was always succeeding.

```
@Service
public class ExampleProvider {

    private OutputResponse outputResponse;

        @Post
        @Path("/test")
        @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
        public OutputResponseEntity execute (InputRequest inputRequest) {

        outputResponse = new OutputResponse();
            outputResponse.setSomeValue("this is test");
            populateOutputResponse();
        }

        private OutoutResponseEntity<OutputResponse> populateOutputResponse () {
            if(null != inputRequest) {
                outputResponse.setSomeOtherValue(inputRequest.getName());
            }
            return new OutputResponseEntity(outputResponse,httpstatus.OK);
        }
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using for `@Service` and the rest of those annotations?

Comment: No, it's not thread safe at all.  You have private, shared data that is mutable.  That's the definition of "not safe".  Remove the private data member and make OutputResponse local to the method.  That's thread safe.

Comment: @duffymo I was expecting the same, creating OutputResponse variable locally inside method is thread safe and keeping it as instance variable "not thread safe" but the load tests succeeds in both cases always..Tried with two threads, initial thread count as 20 and end thread count as 2 in soapui..

Comment: There's no reason for the private data member that I can see.  I'd remove it.  I wouldn't be lulled to sleep by your passing tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code doesn't seem to be quite right, syntactically -- did you mean something like:

```
public OutputResponseEntity execute (InputRequest inputRequest) {
    outputResponse = new OutputResponse();
    outputResponse.setSomeValue("this is test");
    return populateOutputResponse(inputRequest);
}
```

Assuming that's what you meant, then it seems like multiple threads are using the same instance of `ExampleProvider`. That would explain why making `outputResponse` local to `execute` (and then you would probably want to pass it to `populateOutputResponse` too) fixes your tests.

If multiple threads are using the same instance of `ExampleProvider` then, as your code is now, `outputResponse` is also being shared among those threads, and no synchronization is being done to prevent race conditions. So, something like this could happen:

- thread 1 completes `setSomeOtherValue(...)` on the shared instance of `outputResponse`
- JVM context switches to thread 2 and completes `setSomeValue(...)` on the same instance of `outputResponse`. `outputResponse` now contains state from both threads 1 and 2
- JVM context switches back to thread 1, which then creates an `OutputResponseEntity` based on this mixed-state object.

If you make `outputResponse` local to the `execute` method and just pass it around, it effectively becomes thread-local memory, so you'll have a separate instance of that object per thread. This is probably what you want; if you don't need to share information between threads, just make it a local var. If you really do need to coordinate sets/gets between threads (which doesn't seem to be the case in this simple example), then you'll need to do some sort of synchronization and/or design the program flow better (depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

This class is not thread-safe by design. But it's clearly used as a component in some framework. Not it is possible, that this framework ensures that no instance of your `ExampleProvider` is shared between threads. If that's the case, than thread-safety of your class is not a concern and will not influence your tests outcome.

Comment: spring framework is used and per my understanding it creates them as singleton by default, so ExampleProvider gets shared between threads